# Selecting everything except one element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to discover a way of selecting all elements except one specific element. In this case, the `:not(selector)` isn't working.

What's the best way to select all elements inside a container except for one of the specified elements?

```css
.container not:(.test2) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <p class='test'>test</p>
  <p class='test'>test</p>
  <p class='test'>test</p>
  <p class='test'>test</p>
  <p class='test2'>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your colon is misplaced. Should be *before* `not` not after it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct the syntax (add ":" in front of "not"):

```css
.container :not(.test2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test2'>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe * instead of p would be better, as that will really select everything except what is in the condition.

Comment: no need to operate in some tag .. he only need to correct his syntax

Comment: You are right. There are better answers than mine.

Comment: and now it's unfair to change your answer like this ... the OP accepted the old one and this one has a new meaning ... you lead him to a wrong path !

Comment: True, I wanted to delete my answer but it is not possible. So I decided to at least stick to the best one so somebody else can use it (I even voted for @ahmed-masud 's answer).

Comment: @Temani Afif: The whole question is a typo question anyway, so I wouldn't sweat it if I were you.

Comment: @BoltClock true but when I see all these upvotes to the answers given the wrong information am saying : "the asker learned something wrong from this site". So we should at least leave some comments in case the asker get back.

Answer (score 7):

This is the correct syntax, you should match the siblings instead of the parent..

```css
.container *:not(.test2) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test'>test</p>
<p class='test2'>test 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not operator in Your example doesn't work because none of the elements have both .test and .test2. If You leave it like ".container .test {" it will work as well.

Comment: No you don't have to specify the sibling.

Comment: @Ahmed Masud already corrected..

Comment: My mistake already corrected... @zolv

Comment: Your answer's language says that you have to specify a sibling, you don't! You need to Simply use the :not pseudo class to pick the right child. This time you put an element selector, that&#39;s an anti pattern.

Comment: this answer is completely wrong .. not sure how you got all these upvotes !

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.container :not(.test2) {
        color: red;
 }
```

To select everything except `.test2`

All pseudo classes begin with a `:`

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Comment: @user8758206 you accepted a working answer but it's has nothing to do with your issue, you simply had a typo and you don't need any tag selector unless you want more specificity